# How to highlight the specific peptide sequences after performing multiple sequence alignment for the fasta file?

Tags: r, bioconductor, multiple-sequence-alignment

I have the peptide sequences and fasta files separately. I first aligned the fasta files using `msa` package. After that I'm trying to highlight the peptide sequences in the multiple sequence alignment output. I couldn't find a way to do that. Any suggestions on how to do this would be very helpful.

My R script so far:

````r
# load required packages
library(seqinr)
library(msa)
library(dplyr)

# read the file containing the list of peptide sequences
peptides <- read.table("./peptides/AB_hydrolase-1_domain-containing_protein.txt", header=F, stringsAsFactors=F)

# read the file containing the list of fasta files
#hemoSeq <- readAAStringSet(system.file("examples/HemoglobinAA.fasta",package="msa"))
fasta_file <- "./fasta/AB_hydrolase-1_domain-containing_protein.txt"
fasta_data <- readAAStringSet(fasta_file)

# multiple sequence alignment with ClustalW algorithm
msa <- msa(fasta_data, method = "ClustalW")
```
````

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you please define what you "specific peptide sequences"? Perhaps also include the title of the question in the question.

Comment: @M__ I have some short peptide sequences belonging to these fasta sequences, i want to highlight these peptides positions to know their locations in the msa output

Answer (score 1):

Checkout an MSA visualisation and analysis package that you can load the alignment into. It may not be the newest tool, but I've used Jalview (https://www.jalview.org/) in the past

Comment: I have used jalview myself. But I want to do it in a R program